# Have text color change when hover over div

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

I'm trying to have the text color change when you hover over a div, I thought I knew how to do it but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I recreated my div element in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Hhp8s/4/

What I am trying to do is when you hover over the main div id="beginners-guide-box" than the text within the box will change to #0096ff

As you can see in the Jsfilddle what I'm trying is set the color for the div hover but that doesn't work.

```
#beginners-guide-box:hover{
color: #0096ff;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the color of the child div:

```
#beginners-guide-box:hover .beginners-guide-title{
   color: #0096ff;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Also, `.beginners-guide-title` is a div without definition, it spans the parent div, so `.beginner-guide-title:hover` works as well bellow it's master class.

Answer (score 0):

use this full path

```
#beginners-guide-box:hover .beginners-guide-info .beginners-guide-title{
color: #0096ff;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

and delete this:

```
#beginners-guide-box:hover{
    color: #0096ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#beginners-guide-box a:hover {
    color: #0096ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the [specificity of your selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to be greater than that of your `.beginners-guide-title` rule, otherwise those rules will trump the one you created.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Hhp8s/5/)**

```
#beginners-guide-box:hover a div {
    color: #0096ff ;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set color to `.beginners-guide-title` like this:

```
#beginners-guide-box:hover .beginners-guide-title{
    color: #0096ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```